# Week of the quarter, using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to come up with a way to find the week of the quarter, offset by 2 weeks. We do a quarterly software release, on the 3rd Saturday of the quarter (10.15.11, 01.21.12, etc.). Is there way to get that information?

For example, this week would be the 13th week of the quarter.

Comment: 3rd Saturday of the quarter - nice release schedule :)

Comment: Here is the javascript to calculate the week number http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/gregorianwknum.aspx
Add your logic to it and upload the solution if you would.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you want to do it in JavaScript you'll want to start with the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object...

Answer (score 4):

```
function getQuarterWeek(d) {
    // Convert to UTC to avoid DST changes.
    d = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay()));
    // For previous Saturday you would normally add one here.
    // But we want to go back two weeks, so subtract 14.
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() - 13);
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() - d.getUTCDay() - 1);
    // Save the timestamp of this Saturday.
    var s = d.getTime();
    // Now get the first day of the quarter.
    d.setUTCDate(1);
    d.setUTCMonth(d.getUTCMonth() - d.getUTCMonth() % 3);
    // And find the following Saturday.
    d.setUTCDate(7 - d.getUTCDay());
    // Convert the time difference to weeks.
    return (d.getTime() - s) / 604800000 + 1;
}
```